# How can I limit words is React. here is code line<ProductImg imgtext={products.description}/>

Tags: html, reactjs, image, frontend, coding-style

imgAlt={product.name}

example: the product name: **HD Single Sided Cantilever Rack**.
so only **HD Single Sided...** should be printed

Here is code line

```
<ProductImg imgtext={products.description}/>
```

Comment: There are many ways. simplest is using a function (let's say shorter())to cut the name shorter, and then use imgAlt = {shorter(product.name)}

Comment: how can this shorter reduce to 3?

Comment: var y = x.split(' ').slice(0,3).join(' ')+"...";

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
const message = 'HD Single Sided Cantilever Rack.'

const cutTitleFunction = (text) =>{
  return text.split(' ').slice(0,3).join(' ') +'...'
}
console.log(cutTitleFunction(message)) //return HD Single Sided...
```